# Como puedo implementar una funcion amiga para restar dos numeros m1 y m2?

Tags: c++

La funcion que las suma esta dada por: 
En el archivo que contiene el int main():

```
 add(m1,m2, sum); 
 cout << "The sum is:"; 
 sum.display_money();
```

En el archivo .h:

```
 friend void add(AltMoney m1, AltMoney m2, AltMoney& sum);
```

En el archivo .cpp

```
void add(AltMoney m1, AltMoney m2, AltMoney& sum) 
{
 int extra = 0; 
 sum.cents = m1.cents + m2.cents; 
 if(sum.cents >=100){ 
     sum.cents = sum.cents - 100; 
     extra = 1; 
 }

 sum.dollars = m1.dollars + m2.dollars + extra; 
}
```

A partir de esa implementacion quiero restar una de la otra...

La suma a estoy llamando por referencia, pero no encuentro la logica para restar.

Gracias por su tiempo y ayuda.

Answer (score 2):

Las funciones amigas permiten acceder a datos privados de objetos como si dicha función tuviese los permisos de funciones miembro; sin declarar la función como amiga, se aplican las restricciones habituales, por ejemplo:

```
class C
{
    int i;
};

void Suma_1(C &c)
{
    ++c.i; // Error, 'C::i' es privado!
}

int main()
{
    C c;
    Suma_1(c);
    return 0;
}
```

Para que una función sea considerada amiga debe **declararse dentro del objeto** del que se quiere otorgar acceso; de esta manera la función amiga obtendrá los mismos niveles de acceso que los miembros de dicho objeto:

```
class C
{
    // Declaramos la funcion 'Suma_1' como amiga de la clase 'C'.
    friend void Suma_1(C &);
    int i;
};

void Suma_1(C &c) // Definimos la funcio 'Suma_1'.
{
    ++c.i; // Correcto, 'C::i' es privado, pero 'Suma_1' es amiga.
}
```